# Understanding SDP generated by WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I went to chrome://webrtc-internals/ to copy the sdp. Overall, I'd like to understand the meaning.

```
setRemoteDescription

type: answer, sdp: v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-39.0 6618245136742574887 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 27:8B:F6:1A:72:47:17:2B:23:C1:9A:85:AB:3A:E0:29:15:B9:F5:B0:B6:EA:17:C9:11:99:AA:B7:AB:45:A9:60
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:a33017ce6eae687d1afdae61c9f0db55
a=ice-ufrag:f8acf035
a=mid:data
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256
a=setup:active
```

Specifically, I'd like the understand the meaning of

```
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256
```

Comment: Here's a great tool that explains the overall anatomy of SDP ... https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the sctpmap attribute [is defined as](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-sctp-sdp-06#section-5.1):

> The sctpmap attribute maps from a port number (as used in an "m="
> line) to an encoding name denoting the payload format to be used on
> top of the SCTP association or the actual protocol running on top of
> it.

> The sctpmap MUST include the app parameter indicating the application
> running on top of the association.

> The sctpmap line should also contain the max-message-size parameter
> indicating the maximum message size, in bytes, the endpoint is
> willing to accept.

So the line `a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 256` Is indicating port 5000, an application name of 'webrtc-datachannel' and a message size of 256 bytes.

This is in your generated SDP because your application is making use of datachannels on your PeerConnection.